# Can't remove Apex Sharing reason from managed package. Why?

Tags: managed-package, isv, apex-managed-sharing, platform-bug

In my managed package I had a `CustomObject__c` with an Apex Sharing reason. I now want to delete the object from the package. But I can't. 
Because I need to delete the Sharing reasons before. Which I can't..

> This dependency on the Custom Object needs to be explicitly deleted
>   before you can delete this managed Custom Object. Type = Apex Sharing
>   Reason

Platform bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue (still not solved) and opened a case, this is their response:

> A custom object is not deletable if it includes any of the following: Apex Sharing Reason, Apex Sharing Recalculation, Related
>   Lookup Filter, Compact Layout, or Action.
>
> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_managed_component_deletion.htm
>
> See the chart mentioning that the Apex Sharing Reason can't be deleted once published.
>
> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm#packaging_packageable_components
>
> The functionality that you are seeing is WAD. You can create an Idea on Idea Exchange for the same.

TL:DR

As stated [here in the ISV Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf) it's no possible.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? If yes, please post the solution.

Comment: @RahulSharma As stated in the answer, there is no solution, you could create an Idea, that's it.